# JUnit before test parameters

Tags: java, junit

Is there a way to give test somesort of parameters that need to be used before the test is run. Like log in with different account or something like that?

I want to test a webpage. The webpage has different behaviour depending on the user who is logged in. Before each test i would like to switch the user who is logged in. Is there a way to let @Before know what user i want to log in with?

Comment: @Progman got a smart solution. You can specify some params if there are a few not admin users and put this setup in own class because i guess you need to use this in more than 1 test-file which is cleaned up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write helper methods which will do your login. You can use these methods in your tests, depending on what you want to test/check.

```
@Test
public void deleteUserComment() {
    int adminId = this.loginAsAdministrator();
    /*
    ...
    */
}

@Test
public void saveSettings() {
    int userId = this.loginAsUser();
    /*
    ...
    */
}
```

Comment: Maybe i would add a user/type-parameter if there are more than 1 user each type and create a own LoginForTest-Class. @Progman smart solution "bro".

Answer (score 0):

```
int x = 0;

@BeforeEach
public void beforeEach() {
    switch(x) {
        case 0:
            //Log in with user 1
            break;
        case 1:
            //Log in with user 2
            break;
    } 
    x++:
}
```

Should work.

Comment: this maybe working, but you don´t know the chronology the tests get executed. maybe user 4 is logged in and then test 1 gets executed.